# What is the correct way to terminate thread on some condition?

Tags: java, multithreading

some thread perform series of operation in its `run` method. When station closed it inform all its passengers through `onStationClosed`. When it happens thread must to do some action(leaveStation for example) and thread must terminate without finishing all remains operations.

What is the correct way to do it:

```
// 1 - By checking station's state between each operationN?

public class Passenger extends Thread
{
     Station station;
     public void onStationClosed()
     {
          // Do some action before thread terminates
     }
     @Override
     public void run()
     {
         operation1();
         if(station.getState == Station.Closed) return;
         operation2();
         if(station.getState == Station.Closed) return;
         operation3();
         if(station.getState == Station.Closed) return;
         ..
         operationN();
     }
}

// 2 - Throw StationClosedException from onStationClosed and catch it in Station.

public class Passenger extends Thread
{
    Station station;
    public void onStationClosed()
    {
         // Do some action before thread terminates
         throw new StationClosedException();
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        operation1();
        operation2();
        ..
        operationN();
    }
}
```

Comment: How about create a stack of some sort to hold your operations (this would need to be an interface that has an operation() method), then iterate through in a while loop, but checking station state at the start of the loop?

Comment: Using exceptions for control flow is always bad, exceptions should only be used for exceptions. I think the first one is interesting, but still not ideal. Can you explain more about your problem? Why do you need threads? Why can't you use callbacks to signal to the workers that no more work should be done as a station is closed?

Comment: I have station and passengers. Passengers going to station and try to enter the station. Passengers doing what they need in station and once the station close they need to leave it even if they didn't finished doing all what they planned to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first solution is quite good. However not very [dry](/questions/tagged/dry), consider wrapping operations in some small action objects and check the `station` status before executing each operation:

```
List<Operation> operations = Arrays.asList(new Operation1(), new Operation2(), new Operation3());

for(Operation operation: operations) {
  if(!perform(operation)) {
    return;
  }
}
```

Where `perform()` is defined as follows:

```
private boolean perform(Operation operation) {
  if(station.getState == Station.Closed)
    return false;
  operation.run();
  return true;
}
```

A little bit far fetched, but when the number of operations grow, you'll appreciate it.

I don't quite understand the exception solution. If you throw that exception from `onStationClosed()` callback it will be thrown back to your event sender thread, not `Passenger` thread. It won't interrupt your thread.

However you can control this flow using `InterruptedException`. This solution is very similar to checking station status, but instead you check `Thread.isInterrupted()` flag. Added benefit: I/O operations and sleeps are automatically interrupted. All you have to do is calling

```
Thread passenger = new Passenger();
passenger.interrupt();
```

Comment: Using `InterruptedException` is the way to go, since as soon as you add I/O you will need to catch these anyway.

Comment: Just a note, you need to synchronize on Station as you are updating the state of it in one thread and using it in another.